# Get request with query string in express

Tags: json, http, url, express, module

I want to be able to complete a get request on a local host port. The full url should be "localhost:3000/data/mydb.json?get=somefield" where mydb.json can be any filename and somefield is a key. In my app.js file my get request looks like this:

app.get('/data/:filename?get=somefield', routes.getdatabase);

regardless of what i put in the routes file it is unable to complete a get request on any sort of url matching this pattern. To debug i removed everything after the question mark (e.g. app.get('/data/:filename, routes.getdatabase);) and any filename works. Is there some module i need to require in order to use this query string syntax or is there anything else wrong with this get request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings are not a part of the route path.

Given your second example:

```
app.get('/data/:filename', routes.getdatabase);
```

You should be able to use `req.query.get` for your query param.

**routes.js**

```
exports.getdatabase = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.filename);
  console.log(req.query.get);
  // Do some stuff
  return res.send(someResponse);
}
```

Console (URI: /data/someFile?get=cats):

```
someFile
cats
```